# how to to estimate the inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

In fact, my trouble is to get a positive answer for the following inequality, but I can not prove it
$$
\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-\lambda t}t^{-p}\,dt \le C\lambda^{p-1}
$$

where $p>1$ and  $C>0$ is a fix constant.

It is well know when $-p>-1$ it is true since Laplace Transform.

On the other hand, maybe the inequality is not true.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^{1} e^{-\lambda t} t^{-p}dt >e^{-\lambda}\int_0^{1}  t^{-p}dt =\infty$ if $p >1$. Hence, $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} t^{-p}dt $ is also $\infty$.